# how to add a new column every time i run a python program

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

i want my table to have 1st column as roll no,second as name.whenever i run python program i want to add a column of date in table.and in that new column i want to populate the list which i get from user.list will contain values 'P','A','P','P' etc.how to go about it?
i tried first adding a column by alter command and then inserting data but nothing works.

```
choice1=raw_input("\nEnter 'y' or 'n' to add new column:\n")
if choice1 is 'y':
    cursor.execute(" ALTER TABLE table1 ADD datecolumn varchar(20)")
    db.commit()
    for i in xrange(0,10):
        if students[i] is 'A':
            cursor.execute("insert into table1(datetime) values ('A')")
            db.commit()
        elif students[i] is 'P':
            cursor.execute("insert  into table1(datetime) values ('P')")
            db.commit()
```

Comment: Changing your DB design at runtime is maybe not what you really want. What exactely are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I don't know if this is part of your problem, but you shouldn't use `is` to check for equality. Use the `==` operator instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't change your DB design at runtime, but design it in a way that you will change the data not the structure.

You could have two tables. One called `Student` with columns `rollno` and `name`, maybe PK on `rollno` if it is unique.

Then have another table called `Thing` (any suitable name, but I don't know what your data is about) with three columns `when` (datetime), `value` (any suitable name) (CHAR(1)) and `student` (same type as `rollno`).

Define PK over both `when` and `value` to ensure that each student has only one value per date. Define a FK from `Thing.student` to `Student.rollno`. Now your DB takes care of keeping your data (mostly) consistent.

Define indices depending on your needs of selects, inserts and updates over the different columns.

Then for querying join both tables to get the desired result, e.g.

```
select s.name, t.value
from Student s
left join Thing t on t.student = s.rollno
where t.when == 'whenever'
```

(I am not sure about the mysql dialect, so maybe some more quotes are needed. Please feel free to edit.)