# Mysql and python use for attendance system

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to develop a attendance recording system in python and mysql. I have a list which has been populated by 'a' and 'p' values. This list is equal to roll numbers present. Now whenever I run python code, this list should be added to table with datestamp as column.

Now error is every time the code it gives error :
Complete list:-

```
['P', 'P', 'P', 'A', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'A', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P']
```

Absent roll number(s):

```
[4, 9]
```

Present roll number(s):

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

Writing to database:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "take.py", line 47, in <module>
    cursor.execute("ALTER TABLE student ADD column datestamp Date;")`enter code here`

 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler

    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1060, "Duplicate column name 'datestamp'")
```

Comment: As I answered to your last question, and as other two persons have answered here: Changing your DB layout isn't the way to go. Keep the design static and change the data.

Answer (score 2):

Your table definition should be fairly static.  You should only add the `datestamp` column once at design time/deploy time (in most scenarios).  However, your `ALTER TABLE` table statement is trying to add the column to the table every time the code is run which means it will error out every time after it was initially added.  Instead you should be executing insert/update statements to set values for the column, but you haven't really shown enough code for us to provide additional suggestions.

Your question suggests that you have a fundamental misunderstanding of relational database design and it would be best for you to take a step back and make sure you understand those constructs.

Comment: This man posted what I came to say. The error literally says you have a duplicate name conflict.

Comment: This is what I told OP three weeks ago... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233704/how-to-add-a-new-column-every-time-i-run-a-python-program/22234120#22234120

Comment: The problem is what you're asking for is tantamount to writing the entire program for you, teaching you SQL, teaching how to invoke SQL through the Python driver and also explaining how relational databases work.  I don't have time to do that at the moment.  You might get further help from other folks if you post your DDL (table schema) and Python code along with your question, rather than just some of the random bits you think might be relevant.

Comment: problem solved.i learned it on my own.i have been able to insert data in tables.thank you